# How to protect copper pipe buried in screed?

Tags: plumbing, heating

I need to replace a length of 15mm copper pipe buried in screed. How should I protect it?

The copper pipe is part of a 40 year old domestic central heating system (to supply radiators). It seems to be a 'known issue' that copper pipe buried in concrete or screed will (over time) corrode and eventually fail.

I want to replace like-for-like, i.e. new, straight 15mm copper tube but I want to protect the new pipe from failure. The major UK manufacturer of copper pipe sells plastic coated straight copper pipe (sold as 'kuterlex') which seems to be suited for the job, however the two biggest UK retailers don't stock it, and since they supply most of the plumbing professionals to, I'm confused as to what the professional solution is (and where they buy it from). The screed is too shallow to allow the new pipes simply to be insulated before reburial.

(since it's just over a week to Xmas, I'm looking for a solution that I can pick up myself rather than wait for a delivery)

Comment: is the pipe for floor heating  or is it to supply radiators?

Comment: Have you tried looking for Kuterlex where the pro plumbers shop? i.e. at a plumbing supply store, not "the two biggest UK retailers". The two biggest US retailers for home improvement stuff sell a _lot_ of stuff, but it's the big seller items, not the specialty stuff. For that you have to go to a plumbing (or electrical, or...) supplier. Probably actually get a better price there, too. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The proper, professional solution is to use **oxygen barrier PEX** (being closed loop central heating you need the oxygen barrier part) and not copper at all.

It costs less, works fine, won't corrode and does not require protection from cement products.

Wanting to replace copper with copper where copper is unsuitable to the application and has proven so by failing already is a dubious choice. People have "protected copper pipe" by wrapping in tarpaper or plastic before concrete embedment, and the people who own those houses have had to replace failed pipes cast in concrete.

Comment: The original copper pipes imbedded in screed have worked Ok for 42 years out of the last 43 years, if I get half that life-span out of the new copper I'll be quite happy!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

25mm plastic electrical conduit has an inner diameter of about 16.5mm so your 15mm OD copper pipe will fit. Lubricant will facilitate insertion. The conduit will protect it from concrete.

However, copper fittings like elbows or butt joints will not fit, obviously. So it you intend to put an elbow at the end to have a vertical exit to the radiator, then the elbow will be buried in concrete.

A much better solution would be to use pipe specially designed for underfloor hydronic heating: either oxygen barrier PEX as Ecnerwal says, or multiayer pipe which looks much nicer, which can be important if it is visible wherever it comes out of the floor.